# Jenkins method not found when passing no parameter to function

Tags: jenkins

I have a Jenkins shared Library that loads custom methods:

sharedLibrary.groovy

```
def hello(String world) {
    if (world)  {
        echo "${world}"
    }
    else {
        echo "no parameter"
    }    
}
```

The method is used in a Jenkins declarative pipeline

```
stages { 
   stage('Test and Package JAR') {
      steps {
         script {
            sharedLibrary.hello("")
         }
      }
   }
}
```

As long as I call the method with `sharedLibrary.hello("")`or `sharedLibrary.hello("Hello World!")`everything works as expected.

But If I call it with `sharedLibrary.hello()`(using no quotes) I receive the following error even though to my knowledge this is valid groovy code.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'hello' found among steps
```

What is the reason behind this? It seems counterintuitive to pass `""` if I don't want to pass any input at all.

Comment: You create the function with a parameter, so to call it you need to put the parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you're looking for can be achieved with default values:

```
def sayIt(it = "hi"){
  println(it)
}

sayIt()
sayIt("Hello")
```

Also I would only recommend it in cases with very clear and sensible default values.
In the case of "" I would advise against it, since most of the time an empty string is not the result you are looking for.